# publishing images generated by toDataURL() to social networks

Tags: javascript, html, api, html5-canvas, pinterest

I was somewhat successful in generating the image from the HTML5 canvas. Now `toDataURL()` method gives a very very long and weird url. I guess its the binary image. The image shows well in browser.

Now I need to publish that image to some social media (specifically pinterest). Now what do i supply in the media parameter of the "pinit" button?

I tried appending the url I get from thee `toDataURL()` to pinterest pin-it button. but the url for image is like this ([full data-uri here](http://pastebin.com/4QkkA56w)):

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgo [...cut...] bHA0VIAAAAASUVORK5CYII=
```

Now how do i do this? :(

Comment: I think that you need use a server-side tool to generate the images files. for example, your .js got the image content from canvas and send to server to create a file in some folder, after this you can use the file generated.